# send a message to email when the form is successfully submitted using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

when the form is successfully submitted message should be send to email like a notification telling that the registration is done successfully.I want this to be done using Ajax or javascript. Anyone have any suggestions please share...

```
var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
    {
        var msg=x.responseText.trim();
        if(msg=="Thank you for booking and Have a nice Journey!!!")
        {



            alert("Successfully submitted");

           location.reload();
        }
        else
        {
          $.GWSnackbar({id:"snackbar",type:"default",message:"Sorry...Try again"});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a webservice using javamail api and call it from success handler

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/?src=so), which allows sending email from the client side Javascript code using pre-built templates [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an email directly with javascript.

Solution would be to do an ajax call to your server, so that the server sends the email. Be careful not to allow anyone to send any email through your server.

---

You can, however, open the user's mail client:

window.open('mailto:test@example.com');
There are also some parameters to pre-fill the subject and the body:

window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');

Comment: After this above if condition is successfully executed i want the mail to be send.This is connected to jsp

Answer (score 0):

normaly you would do that in your php file, where you actualy save the user data in your database, or where and how exactly do you save your data?

There are a lot of PHP mail libraries out there like this one:
https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/

But as I cant see anything sending to another file in your code right now, so please post more of your code or start to actualy write it and come back if you still have problems!